# Conditional join in SAS

Tags: sql, join, sas, conditional-statements

I have two tables a and b. 
I want to join these two under the following two conditions:

1. a.time1 < b.time1 and b.time1 < a.time2 
   then join a and b on ID
2. b.time1 < a.time1 and a.time1 < b.time2 
   then join a and b on ID

a.

```
ID  Name    Time1                   Time2
1   Joe 01JAN2015:07:02:28  01JAN2015:07:49:13
2   Jenny   01JAN2015:10:06:09  01JAN2015:10:07:11
3   Angie   01JAN2015:07:02:12  01JAN2015:08:00:35
```

b.

```
ID  Name    Time1                   Time2
2   David   01JAN2015:08:19:27  01JAN2015:09:15:29
3   Mike    01JAN2015:10:58:22  01JAN2015:10:59:21
4   Emily   01JAN2015:08:31:18  01JAN2015:08:53:19
```

Can anyone help out?

Comment: Please **proofread your post** before you submit it.  This was a garbled mess of text that made zero sense that you could have easily cleaned up.

Comment: Thanks. this is the first time to post. keep in mind!

Comment: Which Database system are you using? Oracle? MySQL? MS SQL Server? Please comment so the proper tag may be assigned

Comment: @jclozano SAS uses `proc sql` in its software so SQL can be used to mange related datasets. Hence, no RDMS needs to be used in this context.

Comment: @jen - According to your needs, you simply need to join both tables on IDs as either times larger or smaller fits criteria. Possibly you should post desired end results.

Comment: Can you explain in words what those two conditions mean?  It looks like you are asking if the first interval begins during the second interval (and the reverse). None of the examples you post match either of your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
proc sql;
    create table joined_data as
    select * from 
    a
    INNER JOIN
    b
    on a.x=b.x
    where (a.time1 < b.time1 and b.time1 < a.time2 ) 
       or (b.time1 < a.time1 and a.time1 < b.time2 );
quit;
```